# Java: correct way to cast "unsigned" byte to int

Tags: java, int, byte

I have spent several hours on looking for bug in [third-party implementation of stream cipher Rabbit](http://goo.gl/TVwVap). There are several bugs, but one of them:

```
/**
 * @param IV An array of 8 bytes
 */
public void setupIV(final byte[] IV) {
    short[] sIV = new short[IV.length>>1];
    for(int i=0;i<sIV.length;++i) {
        sIV[i] = (short)((IV[i << 1] << 8) | IV[(2 << 1) + 1]);
    }
    setupIV(sIV);
}
```

The problem here is that byte `IV[i << 1]` is casted to `int`, but since Java doesn't have unsigned types, any value `>= 0x80` is casted wrong. Say, byte `0xff` becomes `0xffffffff`, not `0x000000ff` how author of the code above expected.

So I have added simple function:

```
   private int byte2int(byte b){
      int ret = b;
      if (ret < 0){
         ret += 256;
      }
      return ret;
   }
```

It works, but I'm wondering if this is correct way to do what I need? This solution seems dumb somewhat.

Comment: `int result = ((int) unsignedByte) & 0xFF;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure how much this will help, but you may convert a signed byte to its unsigned value by running a binary AND operation with `0xFF`.

Taking this logic further, you could check for overflows after the cast by running a similar AND on the int, with the appropriate operand. This of course assumes that you're always expecting positive or zero valued numbers, or in other words unsigned numbers.

`(short)(((IV[i << 1] & 0xFF) << 8) | (IV[(2 << 1) + 1] & 0xFF))`

The above is the result of putting it all together, courtesy of **Radiodef**.

Comment: Note that `(byte)(b & 0xFF)` is still "signed". You must first cast to int: `((int) b) & 0xFF`

Comment: @Darkhogg: That comment is misleading: A cast to `int` is not required, since `&` promotes its operands to `int` (or `long`, if one of the arguments is of that type). Therefore, the expression `(b & 0xFF)` is of type `int` and yields an "unsigned" value. Of course, one shouldn't cast this value back into a `byte`, as that would make it "signed" again.

Comment: @meriton I personally like to explicitly cast `byte` to `int` as it's easy to lose track of *where* does implicit casts are added, and clearly states intent.

Comment: Putting it together the expression should be `(short)(((IV[i << 1] & 0xFF) << 8) | (IV[(2 << 1) + 1] & 0xFF))`.

Comment: `IV[(2 << 1) + 1]` should be `IV[5]`? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Jan I think it should actually by `IV[(i << 1) + 1]`. Good eye though. Either a copy error or another bug.

Comment: @Jan yeah this is another bug. (I mentioned that there are several bugs) I plan to send the pull request to the author actually: after fixing all these bugs, I have tested this implementation with original C implementation, it works together now.

Answer (score 0):

Use library functions for this operation (in [`ByteBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) class). You will be able to control endianness as a bonus. This will rely on efficiency of Java creators.

```
package tests.StackOverflow.q20776371;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.ShortBuffer;

public class q20776371 {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        byte[] bb = { (byte)0xFF, (byte)0x01, (byte)0x02, (byte)0x03 };

        ByteBuffer buffer1 = ByteBuffer.wrap(bb);

        // set endianness
        // buffer1.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
        // buffer1.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);

        ShortBuffer buffer2 = buffer1.asShortBuffer();

        short[] ss = new short[bb.length>>1];
        buffer2.get(ss);

        for(int i=0; i<ss.length; ++i) {
            System.out.println(String.format("%04x", ss[i]));
        }
    }


}
```